# how to change the date display without changing its posting format

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, date-format

I'm working on a projects in php with twitter bootstrap, css and js; my problem is that when I'm using the bootstrap date-picker then the value is posts in the format like :**dd-mm-yyyy**

Here is my code  for that:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Next Call</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date="dateValue: Customer.DateOfBirth" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input type="text" name="date" data-bind="value: Customer.DateOfBirth" readonly />
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>   
    </div>
    </div>
```

Now In my another page for search by date I have to submit the date according to database so that will matched and give me search value so I did this to matched the value from databse as we know that database stored it in `yyyy-mm-dd` format so i change the line as:

```
 <div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date="dateValue: Customer.DateOfBirth" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
```

But now my problem is that when a user select the value of date its shows in text box as:
`yyyy-mm-dd` and i want to show it as **dd-mm-yyyy** and want to post it as **yyyy-mm-dd**. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Are you saying you want to accept the user input in `dd-mm-yyyy` format and change it to `yyy-mm-dd` to query the database?

Comment: @ Amal Murali : actualy when we click on calendar icon its shows tha calendar and when we select the date it get fill up in textbox as:dd-mm-yyyy as default.and in databse it stored asyyyy-mm-dd.so to match this value from databse i change the format to yyyy-mm-dd.so now i want that it will goes to DB into yyyy-mm-dd format but want to show dd-mm-yyyy into textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assumtions

1. So my understanding is that you currently **are able** to either display the date as `dd-mm-yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd` on the client side
2. You then submit this value to the site (`php`) as a form: `POST` or `GET`

### Solution(s)

Give the above assumptions you then have *two basic* options. One is to alter the date before sending to the server with a client side technology (e.g. `JS`) or to alter it server side (via `PHP`).

Given that you have included the tag `PHP` and not `JS`; we'll focus on that.

#### Method 1

```
$date     = $_POST['date'];                                         // 14-10-2013
$new_date = preg_replace('/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/', '$3-$2-$1', $date); // 2013-10-14
```

#### Method 2

```
$date       = $_POST['date'];                                        // 14-10-2013
$date_array = explode('-', $date);
$new_date   =  $date_array[2].'-'.$date_array[1].'-'.$date_array[0]; // 2013-10-14
```

#### Method 3

```
$date        = $_POST['date'];                 // 14-10-2013
$date_object = new DateTime($date);
$new_date    = $date_object->format('Y-m-d');  // 2013-10-14
```

#### Implementation

You can use any of the methods above and change your code to:

```
$insert_date  = mysql_real_escape_string($new_date);
$query        = "INSERT INTO `comments` SET `date` = '{$insert_date}'";
```

So your final code would look like:

```
$date         = $_POST['date']; //Date from user input
$date_object  = new DateTime($date);
$new_date     = $date_object->format('Y-m-d');
$insert_date  = mysql_real_escape_string($new_date);
$query        = "INSERT INTO `comments` SET `date` = '{$insert_date}'";
```

Comment: @ steven :Here is my code to insert the date :
<?php 
$date=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
$query="insert into comments set date='$date'";
?>
if i'm using the dd-mm-yyyy format in datepicker then how can i insert it as yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Okay, that (see updated answer) should hopefully clarify things for you?

Comment: @ Steven: i have done this but its giving empty value in databse. i have taken my date field as VARCHAR.

Comment: @ Steven : thanks a lot dear.its working like a charm. thatnks a lot for ur precious help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have line of codes like-

```
//suppose $_POST['date'] has 22-09-1990
$dd = $_POST['date'];
$dates = explode('-', $dd);
```

Now the your query will be like -

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO TBLXZ (datecol) VALUES('".$dates[2]."-".$dates[1]."-".$dates[0]."')";
```

I have assumed the table `TBLXZ` is having only one column `datecol` which is of type `Datetime`.

Hope this will help.